# FrontEndObject::notavail ; ParallelSubmit unable to plot using Monitor

Tags: front-end, parallelization, monitoring

I'm trying to `Run` two processes simultaneously;

```
datastream[filepath_, pythoncode_] := Module[{pysession, codename},
   If[StringTake[filepath, -1] == "/",
    codename = StringJoin[filepath, pythoncode],
    codename = StringJoin[filepath, "/", pythoncode]];
   pysession = StartExternalSession["Python"];
   ExternalEvaluate[pysession, File[codename]];
   ];
dataplot[filepath_, prodlabel1_] := 
  Module[{prevln1, bgntm, date, prodate, imprtdata1, dtln1, plt, 
    cmptm},
   prevln1 = 0;
   Monitor[
    While[
     AbsoluteTime[] < 
      AbsoluteTime[
       StringJoin[StringDrop[DateString[AbsoluteTime[Today]], -8], 
        "23:50:00"]],
     bgntm = AbsoluteTime[];
     date = Today;
     prodate = 
      StringDrop[DateString[AbsoluteTime[date], "ISODate"], 2];
     imprtdata1 = 
      Import[StringJoin[filepath, "DATAFILE_", prodlabel1, "_", 
        prodate, ".csv"], "CSV"];
     dtln1 = Length[imprtdata1];
     If[dtln1 > prevln1 && dtln1 > 1,
      Print[dtln1];
      plt = {DateListPlot[imprtdata1[[All, {1, 4}]], Joined -> True, 
         PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 1200, AspectRatio -> 1/9, 
         GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
         FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {Automatic, None}}, 
         PlotLabel -> prodlabel1]};
      prevln1 = dtln1;
      ];
     cmptm = AbsoluteTime[] - bgntm;
     Pause[20 - cmptm];
     ];
    plt, plt]
   ];
```

Individual functions work fine, however, when I'm trying to run them simultaneously using the following code

```
task[i_] := 
 If[i == 1, datastream["/home/csk7/Documents/callPy", "main.py"], 
  If[i == 2, 
   dataplot["/home/csk7/Documents/callPy/deps/data/", 
    "CRUDEOIL22DECFUT"]]]
DistributeDefinitions[task]
Table[ParallelSubmit[{i}, task[i]], {i, 1, 2}]
WaitAll[%]
```

Getting the following error;

```
FrontEndObject::notavail :  A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.
72
Connected
Ticker WS Active...
109
```

The `72`, `109` which are the length of the data file, and `Connected`, `Ticker WS Active...` indicate both codes are running except that the `DateListPlot` under `Monitor` is not working.

ANY SUGGESTIONS, how to fix it, so that it keeps on plotting the data as the data stream is received?

Comment: Can you lookup `UsingFrontEnd` in the documentation and check whether that solves your problem?

Comment: @AlbertRetey: I tried  ```UsingFrontEnd``` in the ```dataplot``` function inside ```task```, before ```DateListPlot```, before ```plt```, before ```Monitor```, however didn't work.

Comment: Do you still get the same message with the `UsingFrontEnd` ? If it doesn't work with it, you would need to find which of the commands is not working. I suggest you try to minimize the problem to the minimal failing code, that will make it more likely someone can help...